# How can we take historical thread dumps in weblogic servers

Tags: java, weblogic12c

A java application process running on weblogic server was reported to have some stuck threads in the past.

Can we get information on those stuck threads from a past time?

Comment: No.  You have to take the thread dumps when the threads are actually stuck.   (Unless you have a [blue box](https://www.amazon.com/Doctor-Tardis-Birthday-Edible-Topper/dp/B00F0WMIAS)  )

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept. Welcome to upvote privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. Gone is gone, end of story.

The only thing you can do is to figure if you can somehow detect such situations while they occur to then collect thread dumps and to log the results.

Worst case you have to give the customers/operators clear instructions how to gather dumps themselves to make them available to you.

Answer (score 1):

If those threads were marked as stuck by WebLogic they were logged in WebLogic server's log file. The stack trace is also logged. Have a look to these log files to see were your threads were stucked.